# PHP - Getting total rows in foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm developing a website and need to get total rows of array in foreach loop.

Here is my code:

```
$vr = $_GET['vr'];

$dat = file_get_contents("http://example.com"); //this is a datafeed url. 

$exp = explode("\n", $dat);

foreach ($exp as $val) {

if($vr == $val) {
// here I have the code if string is found in array. They were found, but I want to get how many were found.
}
```

I tried the `count();` function but it displays `111111111111111111`

I know it's possible but I don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$num = 0;
foreach ($exp as $val) {
    if($vr == $val) {
        $num++;
    }
}
echo $num;
```